# show a trackbar or image while shell() is running a cmd.exe instruction

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, shell

I'm trying to do a simple windows form application in visual basic that change the attributes of all the files in a drive using shell().

It works but since sometimes there are a lot of files, the applications looks like it freeze (because I'm using the "wait" argument as true.

So I'm looking for a way to show an "load" gif while the cmd is doing his thing, I found and example in msdn for a "wait until process finish" using `interaction.Start` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell(v=vs.110).aspx) I tried to mix shell with that example but I can't get it to run ok.

This is my code so far.

```
pic_working.Visible = True

myDrive = "F:\"

Dim procID As Integer
Dim newProc As Diagnostics.Process
newProc = Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Shell("cmd.exe /C attrib -r " + myDrive + "*.* /s /d", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False))


procID = newProc.Id

Dim procEC As Integer = -1
If newProc.HasExited Then
    procEC = newProc.ExitCode
End If
MsgBox("Process with ID " & CStr(procID) & " terminated with exit code " & CStr(procEC))

myDrive =""
pic_working.Visible = False
```

It works...kind of... when I set the wait argument for `shell()` to "true" it take like 30 seconds to complete the task (in my test drive), but with it to false it just skips everything and my pic_Working is never showed.

Can you give me a hint... it's possible to do this in this way, or I have to do the long way (using `File.SetAttributes` and parsing one file at the time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: C++ guy here.

Set Wait to False. If Shell tells you the program is still running, display your image, start a Timer, Use the Win32 API `OpenProcess` with the PID returned by Shell and save the HANDLE, and return. On each Timer Tick, use the Win32 API `WaitForSingleObject` with the HANDLE and with a timout equal to 0. If the process handle is successfully signaled, then the task is terminated.

EDIT

How to know when a process is terminated, when you have successfully got an `HANDLE` to that process with `OpenProcess`:

```
HANDLE hProcess;
[...]
DWORD dwRet = WaitForSingleObject( hProcess, 0 );
if ( dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) {
   // Process is terminated. Don't forget to close the handle
   CloseHandle( hProcess );
} else if ( dwRet == WAIT_TIMEOUT ) {
   // Process NOT terminanted, wait next Timer Tick
} else {
   // Error Occurred
   DWORD dwLE = GetLastError();
}
```

Using the Win32 `HANDLE` type in C#/VB: use `IntPtr`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I on my way to do what you proposed, but Have two problems. -- 1, I'm not sure of what to put in the timer, I need to compare the value returned by `WaitForSingleObject(HandledObject, 0)` to the equivalent to WAIT_OBJECT_0 don't? Can you write the C++ Code so I can translate it to VB ? -- 2. I'm getting an "PInvokeStackImbalance" error and when I use this `HandledObject = OpenProcess(0, True, ProcessID)` to get the HANDLE (or when I use `WaitForSingleObject`). I'm declaring HandledObject as a Long. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again @manuell, I manage to translate all the C++ code to Vb declaring private function for all except `GetLastError` I used instead `Err.LastDllError`. 

I'm still getting 'PInvokeStackImbalance' exceptions in my ticker here: `OpenProcess(0, True, ProcessID)`, I can't find any exact info regarding this. Do you have Any Idea?, because the code never goes beyond that.

Cheers!.

Comment: See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.openprocess Beware: you may want to use `Synchronize` as Access Right, and use false for bInheritHandle.